Which word was used in formal speech instead of "bini" (pairs), if "bini" was impolite because of sounding like the Greek f-word?
I know that Ancient Romans avoided the word "bini" (pairs) because it sounded similar to the Ancient Greek f-word. But which word did they use instead? How would you say "four pairs" in Latin if not "quater bini"?

It's a bit of a stretch to believe Romans as a whole generally avoided bini just because Cicero once mentioned it in one letter.

βινεῖ means rape, a main theme in ancient relegions. So is has nothing to do with US-english definitions of f-words. Greeks and Romans didn't consider sexuality as being 'obscene' in the sense of the laws dealing with offending publications in the puritanical parts of the world.

@RolandF βινέω is not βιάζομαι, despite the likely relation; Aristophanes uses the word three times and never with a connotation of sexual violence. The Romans absolutely did have hang-ups about sexuality (that other Cicero quote: "hodie penis est in obscenis"), they just weren't exactly the same ones we have today.

@Cairnavon Aristophanes as the master of αισχρολογια for a pur male audience is surely not representative, its not so long ago that - at least on the continent - rape was considered a possibility. My Stowasser has rape, force for βινεῖ  only. Cicero, as always,knows and  has both views, puritan Roman republican or Greek hedonism while for a break at Pompeji.

Based on Cicero's Ad Fam 9.22, you mean?

Cum loquimur "terni," nihil flagiti dicimus; at cum "bini," obscenum est? "Graecis quidem," inquies. Nihil est ergo in verbo, quoniam et ego Graece scio et tamen tibi dico "bini"…
When we say "triples", we're saying nothing shocking, but when we say "pairs", it's obscene? "It certainly is to the Greeks", you might object. Then there's nothing [obscene] in the [form of the] word, because I know Greek, and I still say "pairs" to you.

He then goes on to argue that it's all nonsense: that words can't be obscene, and meanings can't be obscene, so obscenity can't really be a thing that exists.
But it doesn't seem like other Roman authors agreed with his friend. Cicero himself used the word quite freely in other contexts! It looks like that anecdote about bini and Greek βινεῖ was just an illustrative example; there's no real evidence that Roman authors actually avoided talking about "pairs" as a result.

If I'm reading this right, then from context it is pretty clear that Cicero does not think bini is obscene in Latin and intends to continue to use it. Packhum even has a question mark after obscenum est, and Graecis quidem ought to be translated "to the Greeks it certainly is."

Full context: Cum loquimur 'terni', nihil flagiti
dicimus; at cum 'bini', obscenum est? 'Graecis quidem' inquies. nihil est ergo in verbo, quoniam et ego Graece scio et tamen tibi dico 'bini', idque tu facis quasi ego Graece non Latine dixerim.

@SebastianKoppehel Good point! The text I was looking at on Perseus doesn't have a question mark there, but the Loeb does, and it makes much more sense with that. I'll change my translation.

My only minor quibble is with the last sentence, in that that the word does appear to be conspicuously absent among most "Golden Age" writers. No Caesar, Catullus, Sallust, Vergil, Horace, Tibullus, Propertius, or Ovid. Besides the two writing about words (Cicero and Varro), really only Nepos and Livy remain, and Livy isn't know for his Greek proficiency. There is indeed an absence, but maybe not something that Romans in general felt. Perhaps only those who were more attuned to its homophonous Greek profanity?

@cmw Comparing against attestations of terni, though, it doesn't seem so striking. I assumed that was just an accidental gap: there are plenty of specific word forms that Caesar never used.

@Draconis That's certainly also possible, although terni has fewer attestations overall and doesn't even show up in Plautus (edit: i.e., could it have been a later coinage based on bini?), whereas bini does. Also, that Cicero made the argument against its being obscene suggests that someone else argued for it. None of this is definitive, of course, but I don't think it's a far-fetched hypothesis. (And whatever might have been true at some point certainly ceased being so by the 1st century CE. The absolute nature of the OP characterization would still be too simplistic.)

@Sebastian Koppehel: In "idque tu facis quasi ego Graece non Latine dixerim," why did Cicero use the perfect subjunctive, "dixerim"? Is it because he did not actually speak in Greek?

@tony yes, I believe that's correct. Quasi can stand with the indicative, but that tends to be the case when the meaning is more akin to “just like” (often with ita, sic); but here we have “as if,” a counterfactual that usually stands with the subjunctive. I wonder if this can be fit into the usual taxonomy of condicionals, seeing how quasi is, of course, qua si; in this case, would this be a “future less vivid” condicion, and if so, what does the perfect mean?

Had to stop my phone from inserting the misspelling “condition” twice, whom do I have to call at Google to put an end to this
